# AWS IAM: How does the condition context key "aws:RequestTag" work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-policy

I have an EC2 instance with a role attached to it. My goal is to provide full access to AWS service (Lambda for example) but only on certain resources (Tag based). I found that `aws:RequestTag` was the way to do it.

Below is the IAM policy attached to the role.

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1614664562621",
            "Action": "lambda:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/app": "prod"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I added the tags `app:prod` on the required lambda functions but however when I try to list the lambda I get an `AccessDeniedException` error. Below is the error message

> An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the
> ListFunctions operation: User:
> arn:aws:sts::123456789:assumed-role/iam-role-name/i-01abcd456abcd is
> not authorized to perform: lambda:ListFunctions on resource: *

How to make the `aws:RequestTag` work? Where am I going wrong?

Similar question below: (That solution didn't work for me)
[aws:RequestTag on s3 bucket is not working (while assuming a role)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62682497/awsrequesttag-on-s3-bucket-is-not-working-while-assuming-a-role)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use `aws:ResourceTag` instead in your condition and tag the resources (i.e. Lambda functions) that this policy should permit access to.

`aws:RequestTag` is used to control which tags *can be* carried in an AWS API call such as for adding/editing/removing a resource tag on a resource or adding session tags on a session (via an `sts:TagSession` call). They are not meant to protect access to resources *having* a specific tag.

Also, adding the tag on your role does not mean that any caller identity (i.e. assumed session role) will then have this tag as a request/session tag. And consequently, it will not control any authorization/access to resources with that tag. The IAM role that you tagged simply is *another* AWS resource with a resource tag applied to it now.

Additionally, you couldn't even control session tags when EC2 assumes your role in the EC2 instance, so you cannot control session/request tags for your EC2 instance.

EDIT: In your particular example with `lambda:ListFunctions`, though, which is *not* a resource-specific action, you cannot control/filter the list by Lambda functions having a specific resource tag allowed by the policy of the API caller.

When working with multiple environments/stages, having multiple AWS accounts (one per environment/stage) is actually best practice. You can then even use *AWS Organizations* for consolidated billing, etc. if you don't already use multiple AWS accounts.

Comment: your reply makes sense, but unfortunately I did try with `resourcetag` also and still ended up with the same error. Have updated the question with new policy

Comment: Yes, you are right. my bad. Listfunctions won't apply for this case. When I tried a resource specific action, it worked. Answer accepted